# wkhtmltopdf ignore CSS style in input fields

Tags: css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I would like to generate a editable PDF with some input fields, but when I chage the value od this input fields the font-size in those fields are very different to default font. I tried to set font-size by styling css, but it doesn't work. How can I set font-size or other css properties in input fields?

I'm ussed 0.12.0 version.

I managed set border properties, or size of the field by css, but font-size is ignored.

Comment: Unresolved issue ticket: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=944

Comment: If you include the css right into the style property of the text wrapping object then, rather than in the header or included, then it is more likely to detect it.